# Can the robot play other expansions?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

Can the robot used to play the single player variant added by The Gather Storm expansion be used to played with other expansions (or the base game without the addition of the Gather Storm cards), or can it only be used to play The Gathering Storm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two other expansions in the first arc (*Brink of War* and *Rebel vs Imperium* come with a few additional components that allow the Robot to use starting worlds from those expansions.

There is no official rules for the robot for playing with the *Alien Artifacts* expansion, however there are [non-official rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/103929/solitaire-game-alien-artifacts) available on Boardgamegeeks.